# Is $Y_s=sB_{1\over s},s>0$ a brownian motion

Tags: probability

Suppose $\{B_s,s>0\}$ is a standard brownian motion process. Is $Y_s=sB_{1\over s},\ s>0$ a brownian motion or (stardard). I have found that $Y_0=0$ and $Y_s\sim N(0,1)$ as $B_s\sim N(0,s)$, so it remains to show that it is stationary increment and independent increment. But i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: You have $Y_s \sim N(0,s)$ (as it should be) ;-)

Comment: I changed $B_s$~$N(0,s)$ to $B_s\sim N(0,s)$, coded as B_s\sim N(0,s).  That is standard usage.

Comment: @martini why? $B_{1\over s}\sim N(0,{1\over s})$ isn't it?

Comment: It is, but $\lambda N(0,\sigma^2) \sim N(0,\lambda^2\sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of Gaussian processes ? If you have, you only have to check that $(Y_s)$ has the same covariance function as the Brownian motion.

If you haven't, don't worry, it's very simple here: you are interested in the law of the couple $(sB_{1/s},tB_{1/t}-sB_{1/s})$ when $0 < s <t$. This is a 2 dimensional centered Gaussian vector, so its law is entirely determined by its covariance matrix. In the end, you have to compute $E(sB_{1/s} tB_{1/t})$.

Comment: i am checking about the gussian process. By the way, for the second method, i wonder if you are trying to show $cov(Y_t,Y_s)=s$?

Comment: First, the two methods are in fact the same. Second, I'm not trying to show anything, you are. Anyway trying to show that $cov(Y_t,Y_s)=\min(s,t)$ is a good intuition.